# D3.js visualization is lagging

Tags: javascript, d3.js

the following d3.js visualization is lagging when opened in a browser. At first it runs smoothly but later visualization becomes lagging. As it seems it consumes lot of memory. Also when i tried reducing the number of records in the csv file, it runs a little smooth.

```
d3.csv("csv/EditedCSVFile.csv",function(capitalsArray){
         var noOfTweets = capitalsArray.length;
          var i = 0;
          var intervalId = setInterval(
              function() {
               if (i == capitalsArray.length) {
                  clearInterval(intervalId); // stops executing once we've browsed through the array
                  alert("Simulation Completed...");
               } else {

                  var score = capitalsArray[i].score;

                   if(score =="1"){
                      var colCode = "#ff0000";
                   }
                   if(score =="2"){
                      var colCode = "#00ff00";
                   }
                   if(score =="3"){
                      var colCode = "#0000ff";
                   }
                   if(score =="4"){
                      var colCode = "#ff00ff";
                   }
                   if(score =="5"){
                      var colCode = "#00ffff";
                   }
                  //console.log(colCode);
                   // Plotting starts here
                   canvas.selectAll(".city-marker")
                   .data(capitalsArray)
                   .enter().append("circle")
                   .attr("r",20)
                   .attr("fill", colCode)
                   .attr("opacity", 0)
                   //.attr("stroke-width","1")
                   .attr("cx",function(d){
                      var coords = projection([capitalsArray[i].Lat, capitalsArray[i].Long]);
                      //console.log(coords[0]+", "+coords[1]);
                      return coords[0];
                   })
                   .attr("cy",function(d){
                      var coords = projection([capitalsArray[i].Lat, capitalsArray[i].Long]);
                      //console.log(coords[0]);
                      return coords[1];
                   })
                   .transition()
                   .attr("r",4)
                   .attr("opacity", 1.0)
                   .duration(1000);
                   //Plotting ends here
                   //console.log("Cordinates: "+capitalsArray[i].Lat+" "+capitalsArray[i].Long);
                   i++;
               }
           },
           10
       );

  });
```

Comment: I cannot test your code (no data) but the first (minor) thing I saw was the replace of `if(score...)` with a dictionary. Moreover, it seems that you do the same thing over and over: initialize the `canvas` with data `x times` where `x` is the length of your data. Could you please explain why? Is it really the result you want? Lastly, I've found that transitions tend to slow wayyy down the visualization.

Comment: I mean, it seems to me you are trying to perform a visualization/ transition but you keep initializing your data every time `canvas.selectAll(".city-marker")
                   .data(capitalsArray)
                   .enter().append("circle")
                   .attr("r",20)
                   .attr("fill", colCode)
                   .attr("opacity", 0)`. 
You can initialize your canvas with data once and then loop `x times` your data and change the cx/ cy accordingly to provide the visual effect. (Correct me if I have not understood what your are trying to do correctly) :)

Comment: You are right on the point. That's exactly i want to know. The thing is previously When i try to initialize the data once and loop the visualization it did not work. That is exactly why i have initialized the data in every iteration. I think that is why the visualization consumes more memory right? So how can i Do that. I mean initialize the data once and iterate for each element in the CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, your code is slow and hangs because it creates over and over the city-marker canvas element.

Ok, so this is untested, since I don't have the data, but the point is that, you need to initialize your chart/element with the data **once** and then loop to make the transition as you want.

I've also made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33LLjtnL/) with an example of the following code and some sample data.
And found this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997 that may be partially what you want out of the transition.

(I believe that the loop with the transition is not the most effective way and that there must be another easier way to achieve what you want, but since I don't really know what you want the end result to be, let's stick with that :) )

```
d3.csv("csv/EditedCSVFile.csv", function(capitalsArray) {

  var scoreToColor = {
    "1": "#ff0000",
    "2": "#00ff00",
    "3": "#0000ff",
    "4": "#ff00ff",
    "5": "#00ffff",
  }
  // set up your element with the data and save it for further use
  var cityMarkerCanvas = canvas.selectAll(".city-marker")
    .data(capitalsArray)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return scoreToColor[d.score];
    });

  // iterate through the element's data and set the cx, cy and
  // well, control the transition as you wish
  cityMarkerCanvas.each(function(d) {
    // calculate the coords once
    var coords = projection([d.Lat, d.Long]); 

    d3.select(this)
     .transition()  // move the transition here maybe for a better effect?
     .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return coords[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return coords[1];
      })
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("opacity", 1.0)
      .duration(1000);
  })
});
```

Or, something along these lines.

Hope this helps! Good luck!

**edit**: A way to handle the timing of the transition: https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/9g3j39mt/ with the use of `d3.timeout`